# How to render my data inside a table and rendering real-time data (like stock price)

Tags: react-native, html-table, react-redux, stock

Nifty50 is a component of my react-native application in which my objective is to display the data from the json-server, which contains data in this format:

```
{
    "nifty50":
        [
            {
                "CompanyName": "Adani Ports and Special Economic Zone Ltd.",
                "Industry": "SERVICES",
                "Symbol": "ADANIPORTS",
                "Series": "EQ",
                "ISINCode": "INE742F01042\r"
            },
            {
                "CompanyName": "Asian Paints Ltd.",
                "Industry": "CONSUMER GOODS",
                "Symbol": "ASIANPAINT",
                "Series": "EQ",
                "ISINCode": "INE021A01026\r"
            },
            ...
        ]
}
```

The Nifty50 component is as follows:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { FlatList} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import { ListItem } from 'react-native-elements';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        nifty50 : state.nifty50
    }
}

class Nifty50 extends Component
{
    render()
    {
        const renderStocks = ({item, index}) => {
            return(
                <ListItem 
                    //onPress = {() => navigate('Details', {isinCode : item.isinCode})}
                    key = {index}
                    title = {item.Symbol}
                    subtitle = {item.CompanyName}
                    hideChevron = {true}
                />
            );
        }
    
        return(
                <FlatList 
                    data = {this.props.nifty50.nifty50}
                    renderItem = {renderStocks}
                    keyExtractor = {item => item.ISINCode}
                />
        );
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Nifty50);
```

But this renders the "Symbol" and "Company Name" in simple list form, but I need to render them in tabular form and to show the details of each stock such as price and Market Capital in real-time.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of ListItem, return a View.

```
<TouchableOpacity>
    <View>
        // All details goes here
    </View>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I also suggest putting your renderStocks() outside the render() method.

Comment: actually the renderStocks() renders one item in my list at a time, so it will be called everytime the component renders, right?